# How to apply filters on second ngRepeat in nested ngRepeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I want to apply $filter from search box to nested ng-repeat. I have an array of categories, each categories contains a list of items. When I put $filter on 1st ngRepeat, it filters & keep the category which have the correct items. However, I just want to filter in the list of items.

I have created a Plnkr to show my example. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/KIsn9ZPuIqUMlwkORnrE

```
angular.module('myapp',[])
.controller('AllCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.data = [
      {name: "ebooks", items: [
        {name: "Learning AngularJS", type: "pdf"}, 
        {name: "Learning Javascript", type: "pdf"},
      ]},
      {name: "books", items: [
        {name: "AngularJS for dummy", type: "old"},
        {name: "Javascript for dummy", type: "new"}
        ]}
    ];
});
```

HTML file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.3" data-require="angular.js@*"></script>
    <script data-require="firebase@*" data-semver="1.0.18" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" data-semver="3.3.1" data-require="bootstrap-css@*" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myapp">
    <div class="col-md-9" ng-controller="AllCtrl">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here..." ng-model="search" />
      <div style="height: 10px"></div>
      <div ng-repeat="cat in data | orderBy: 'name' | filter:search">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">{{$index +1}}</button> Category: {{cat.name}}
            <dl class="dl-horizontal" ng-repeat="item in cat.items">
          <dt>{{item.name}}</dt>
          <dd>{{item.type}}</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Please help me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter inner item list then specify the filter in that list itself.

Putting filter for inner `ng-repeat` has solved your problem.

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in data | orderBy: 'name'">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">{{$index +1}}</button> Category: {{cat.name}}
    <dl class="dl-horizontal" ng-repeat="item in cat.items | filter:search">
        <dt>{{item.name}}</dt>
        <dd>{{item.type}}</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Here is [**Working Fiddle**](http://plnkr.co/edit/JnOedvf5pIYGCKBr0oZt?p=preview)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: when I am trying code in Fiddle, it's working. However, when I am trying with code in my app, it doesn't work. I don't know why =)) My $scope.data is returned from Firebase as Array.

Comment: Could you please paste your resposnse array here, ehich you are getting inside `$scope.data`